# How do I stop my screen from reverting to previous states?

Tags: xubuntu, screen

I am using Xubuntu 14.04. It performs fine normally, but every once and a while, the screen starts acting strangely. It suddenly switches to showing a state it was previously in - for example, while working in Aptana Studio, it will sometimes display the work I was doing a few hours beforehand. This happens with other programs too, though, such as when I switch to my browser, it will display Aptana Studio.

Even when it displays the previous state, I am still able to interact with the window that's really on top. Making any changes (such as hovering over a link, or scrolling) causes that area to show what it's supposed to, but the rest of the screen stays showing the old state.

(I previously thought that the problem didn't occur across workspaces, but I've now seen that it does.)

Any ideas what could be going on? Is there any other information I could share to help diagnose the problem?

Additional info from the comments:

Java version: Java 7 update 55 64-bit

GPU info: NVIDIA Corporation: G92 [GeForce 9800 GTX+]: Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)

I tried switching the GPU driver to "NVIDIA Binary Driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)", but it had no effect.

Comment: I don't know Aptana but I gather it is a Java application. Other Java applications sometimes expose similar issues. Which version of Java is installed?

Comment: @aquaherd Correct, it's an IDE built off of Eclipse. I have Java 7 update 55 64-bit installed.

Comment: Sounds like a GPU bug. What GPU do you have?

Comment: @bain Here's what I got from "Additional Drivers" - NVIDIA Corporation: G92 [GeForce 9800 GTX+] and Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source).

Comment: Report a bug to the Nouveau project at http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/Bugs/

Comment: @bain It looks like it isn't Nouveau exclusive. I switched my driver to NVIDIA's recommended driver, "NVIDIA Binary Driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)", with no effect.

Comment: If it occurs under both drivers that suggests it might be a hardware glitch, which could be caused by bad seating in the PCI slot, bad onboard graphics RAM, overheating etc. Or it could be a software problem at a higher level (does it only affect Java applications?), but that would be unusual, it still sounds like a graphics card/driver issue.